# dynamic onclick function not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using onclick function which is add dynamically using ex:

```
.attr('onclick','test()');
```

---

which one is works perfectly in chrome and safari but in firefox function calling fails. manually function calling from the console is working but onclick do not.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: use `.on('click', test)`

Comment: @Tushar, `.attr('onclick','test()');` should work just fine..

Comment: i am adding onclick as following   from another function $("#tune_new_loadmore").attr("onclick","load_content('new',2);");       function load_content(type,click_type) 
{   alert();   }

Comment: Depends on which scope `test` is defined in, if it is global scope `onclick` attribute should work, if not it won't work

Comment: That's weird, never seen anyone trying to add this attribute. Like above said use .on('click', test)

Comment: can you post your html code where you use that #tune_new_loadmore id ??

Comment: test was just an example .i am using the load_content() function wich having 2 arg. and the arguaments are dynamic so i have to set the onclick using attr from another function. its works perfectly in chrome and safari .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cwasj1r4/1/ - The first doesn't work, where as second one is working

Comment: <span id="tune_new_loadmore" class="load-more-text">Load More</span>    @Akhilesh Singh

Comment: <span id="tune_new_loadmore" class="load-more-text" onclick="">Load More</span> use this sometimes firefox failed to detects . @ Rafik malek

Comment: @ArunPJohny from your fiddle can you tell why one wont work while two will work that would be greate for reader like me

Comment: @guradio see my first comment.. it is related to the scope in which the function is defined... the `onclick` attribute will look for the function in the global scope

Comment: @Rafikmalek look at your browser console, is there any error logged

Comment: no error .first i checked there thats why i was not gettign idea to finding error. @arun

Answer (score 0):

It works in firefox as well. Here is an example
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/porfirion/js3LweLj/)

```
$('button').attr('onclick', 'alert("hello")');
```

I guess you could have a mistake somewhere else, causing no to work in firefox. Or may be you have very old version on firefox?